# How to use SQL script variable (postgresql) in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

I am running sql code through Jupyter notebook (connected using SQL Alchemy engine) to fetch data from DB, while everything works smooth I've hit a wall when trying to use variables.

E.g., here's a dummy script that's running on  my notebook

```
select * from table1 where employees = 50
```

I need to use a variable for 50. On SQL client I would define a variable and use colon to use it, but that code is giving me a syntax error on Jupyter notebook, which was sort of expected.

Anyone knows how to use pre-defined variables on Jupyter notebook when running SQL queries so I don't have to keep editing scripts every day? Any help is very much appreciated.

What I tried:

```
num = 50
script = '''select * from table1 where employees = :num'''
```

resulted in a syntax error

Comment: Do you want to use formal parameters for this or just create a SQL statement that includes your variable?

Comment: f strings might help with this. script = f"select * from table1 where employees = {num}"

Comment: @Josh fstring worked like a charm, thanks a lot. I learned something new, really appreciate your help.